# Image Perspective Cropping with edge detection in android

Tags: java, android, image, opencv

i am working in a document scanner application where scan the document through camera and perspective crop the image with edge. i follow this link [enter link description here](https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo/issues). It is working fine but i am going to publish then playstore show this issues "libpng vulnerability issue when publishing app using this library. How to upgrade the libpng in this library". How to resolve this issues? or any other library which working ?

Comment: library solve the issue.:)

Answer (score 1):

The vulnerable version of libpng was updated in OpenCV 2.4.13.1. You can download it [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/2.4.13.1/).

More info: [#6694 OpenCV 2.x uses vulnerable version of libpng](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6694)

Comment: ,thanks for your reply.but when click on download then its not downloading

Comment: It's working for me. Try this [direct link](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-android/2.4.13.1/OpenCV-2.4.13.1-android-sdk.zip?r=https%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fopencvlibrary%2Ffiles%2Fopencv-android%2F2.4.13.1%2F&ts=1476363923&use_mirror=heanet).

Comment: ,i can download it ,then need to replace sdk into jni?

Comment: i replaced sdk from your link..but app is rejected by google

Comment: How are you importing the library? Do you use async or static initialization? Could you provide more details?

Comment: As I see, scanlibrary is using OpenCV 2.4.11 and it is initializing OpenCV in a static way (not recommended for production by the way). To update it, you have to replace the actual OpenCV SDK and native libs by the last version.

Comment: i have download latest sdk and replace into sdk but not working,can you give step how can it will working?